# Q: How to enable dock microphone by default when headphones with mic are plugged-in?

Tags: sound

When I plug or unplug my JBL headphones with mic, the sound is being adjusted (for example, if I previously had the volume turned off when I unplug my headphones the volume becomes muted, and vice versa).

For some reason, I'm not able to make the elementary OS Juno to automatically select Dock Microphone by default when I plug them in thus I have to manually switch it every time. Do you have any ideas of how this could be set up so that when the headphones with the mic are plugged in, the system automatically uses the headphone's mic instead of a built-in one?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't check if eOS has `pulseaudio` installed by default right now, if it's not there then `apt install` first. Then follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113704/make-pulseaudio-prefer-external-audio-device) to automatically switch to a newly connected device.